# How can I parse json in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, json, parsing

I have a JavaScript file containing the following object:

```
var MoceanSettings={
       BannerURL:'',
       IsDirectWall:true,
       AppOfDayZone:156431,
       ImpressTrackUrl:null,
       ClickTrackUrl:null,
       Categories:[
          {name:'App Gallery', Zone_T:165294,Zone_M:165295,Zone_B:165296},
          {name:'Entertainment', Zone_T:165306,Zone_M:165307,Zone_B:165308},
          {name:'Games', Zone_T:165297,Zone_M:165298,Zone_B:165299},
          {name:'Lifestyle', Zone_T:165309,Zone_M:165310,Zone_B:165311},
          {name:'Productivity', Zone_T:165303,Zone_M:165304,Zone_B:165305},
          {name:'Travel', Zone_T:165300,Zone_M:165301,Zone_B:165302},
          {name:'Favorites', Zone_T:156431,Zone_M:156431,Zone_B:156431}
       ]
}
```

Using java I would like to parse this file into an object/array. I have a very limited working knowledge of JavaScript and json.

Comment: you can not store JavaScript expressions in JSON format, you should just take the value of the needed Object

Comment: You need to pass object MoceanSettings through ajax (whatever you are using like dwr, jQuery). At server side, you should have same MoceanSettings POJO object, it will be automatically convert to POJO object.

Comment: @micnic ok, so can I read it as a String? But how can I read specific element from the .js file?

Comment: @Deepu, I would use an JavaScript interpreter like a browser or node.js and send the needed object to the Java application

Comment: @micnic, I will research on JavaScript Interpreter, I thought in Java there will be some mechanism for parsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class ExecuteScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(ExecuteScript.class.getResourceAsStream("javascript.js")));
    printJSElement("root", engine.get("MoceanSettings"));
    }

    private static void printJSElement(String propName, Object element) {
        if (element instanceof List) {
            printJSList(propName, (List<Object>) element);
        } else if (element instanceof Map) {
            printJSMap(propName, (Map<Object, Object>) element);
        } else {
            printJSProperty(propName, element);
        }
    }

    private static void printJSMap(String propName, Map<Object,Object> objectMap) {
        for (Entry<Object,Object> entry : objectMap.entrySet()) {
            printJSElement(propName + "." + String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static void printJSList(String propName, List<Object> objectList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
            printJSElement(propName + "[" + i + "]", objectList.get(i));
        }
    }

    private static void printJSProperty(String propName, Object value) {
        System.out.println(propName + " = " + value);
    }

}
```

This would present following output:

```
root.BannerURL = 
root.IsDirectWall = true
root.AppOfDayZone = 156431
root.ImpressTrackUrl = null
root.ClickTrackUrl = null
root.Categories[0].name = App Gallery
root.Categories[0].Zone_T = 165294
root.Categories[0].Zone_M = 165295
root.Categories[0].Zone_B = 165296
root.Categories[1].name = Entertainment
root.Categories[1].Zone_T = 165306
root.Categories[1].Zone_M = 165307
root.Categories[1].Zone_B = 165308
root.Categories[2].name = Games
root.Categories[2].Zone_T = 165297
root.Categories[2].Zone_M = 165298
root.Categories[2].Zone_B = 165299
root.Categories[3].name = Lifestyle
root.Categories[3].Zone_T = 165309
root.Categories[3].Zone_M = 165310
root.Categories[3].Zone_B = 165311
root.Categories[4].name = Productivity
root.Categories[4].Zone_T = 165303
root.Categories[4].Zone_M = 165304
root.Categories[4].Zone_B = 165305
root.Categories[5].name = Travel
root.Categories[5].Zone_T = 165300
root.Categories[5].Zone_M = 165301
root.Categories[5].Zone_B = 165302
root.Categories[6].name = Favorites
root.Categories[6].Zone_T = 156431
root.Categories[6].Zone_M = 156431
root.Categories[6].Zone_B = 156431
```

Comment: Thanks Java Mentor, I'll definitely try this.

Comment: I m getting error **java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject cannot be cast to java.util.Map** on the line - **printJSMap("root", (Map<Object,Object>)engine.get("MoceanSettings"));**

Comment: what do you have in your js file? I executed it locally, but within my file is just the javascript piece you posted

Comment: Only the contents I have given in the question ** var MoceanSettings =  ** etc

Comment: I just change the code, please update to check. (  `printJSElement("root", engine.get("MoceanSettings"));`)

Comment: I am getting output as - **root = [object Object]**

Comment: Please try the following sample: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4068397/javascript-test.zip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27391/discussion-between-java-mentor-and-deepu)